# Flutter Web - App Reloads on Browser resizing using inspect

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web-browser

I've been developing a flutter web app with multiple screens. Actually my issue comes when I tries to resize my browser window my app reloads with first page of the app with some errors. I was struck on how to handle this type of issues. Can anyone help me on this ?